# Archive Tables - Old Copies

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a program that keeps track of games being played for the year.  Once that year is done I was planning to allow admin to archive that season.  To do this I created a copy of that table with a name for the previous season.  I stored that name in a separate table.

Problem is I guess I cannot do sql query with the table name generated from the table.

Anyone have any advice on how to handle this.  The table could have 1000-2000 records per year, and this could be in place in 20 years (probably not with technology).  I could add a column for year and use that as a sort, but is it going to get slow when I hit 20K - 40K worth of records?

Another idea I had is keep the active year in one table and archive all the history to another separate one? Users don't care if history takes a few seconds to load, but not current data?

Thanks

Comment: if you have a properly indexed table it will not be slow with 40k records. Adding an index on year is obvious, but read up on indexes a little more. You can use `EXPLAIN` to find out where you query is slow (if it is)

Comment: You shouldn't really bother about performance, when there will be only 40k records in your table

Comment: Right now it is really quick, it is only 1000 records. I am just trying to plan for the future and I thought a separate table for each year.

I do have one other challenge, I have the teams listed in a separate table and do a join to get the standings.  Not sure how to archive the teams, I will have to figure a way to add a date to that also.

Comment: It is not going to be slow in 1000 years at that rate. Databases are very good at doing things quickly even on large tables. Just add a column isDeleted and set it to true (or 1) when you want to archive something. I'd consider 40K records insignificant in terms of DB size and wouldn't even START considering performance impact at that number. At 1-2M it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Slowness is a function of query complexity as much as it is of record size. You can make slow queries with a 100 rows or fast ones with millions. If you need specific help on query optimization, post it, otherwise there isn't much to work with, except the previously suggested indexes.

Generally a 10k order of magnitude will do nothing special. Don't try to overoptimize before you actually identify the weak points. Partitioning the tables is **very** rarely neccessary before hitting millions, if not tens of millions, of rows. You're falling into the 'premature optimization' trap. Don't do it unless you're certain it's going to cause problems.

Me, I'd throw an index on the columns you use to `JOIN` the table (probably `user_id`) and be done with it. There's an automatic one on it if you're using foreign keys. Until you see your queries slowing down the application, you'd probably do more harm than good by forcing it to work around partitioning.